# jwplayer: Error loading player: No playable sources found in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, embed, jwplayer

We are using following script for live streaming for our platforms?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/emowlss.js"></script>
<script>jwplayer.key="PnGAasdfasdfh/oIOasdfasdfsadf9nqNZmG0="</script>
jwplayer("livestream_container").setup({
file: feedurl, 
autostart:false, 
autoplay : false,
'controlbar': 'bottom',
image:img,
stretching:"exactfit",
width:"100%",
});

<div id="livestream_container" > </div>
```

Live streaming is not happening and default image also not showing in player. Its showing following error image?

> Error loading player: No playable sources found

Comment: If you're using JW Platform, you should be able to sign on to your account, upload your file, and get a auto generated script.

Comment: yes we are using like that way, but what file need to upload into my account

Comment: The video perhaps? When you see that error it's either: 1. you don't have a readable file. or 2. You don't have a file at all.

Comment: I have the valid streaming url, that's playing  in following online tool : https://www.hlsplayer.net/.

Comment: Download latest library file and added "jwplayer/jwplayer.js" instead of following include cloud library <script type="text/javascript" src="http://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/emowlss.js"></script> , this will be working good.

Comment: Any idea about why there restricting cloud library?

Comment: >Error loading player: No media sources found
This means you either did not specify a media source to play, or your setup block is incorrect. Please see Embedding the Player for info on the file and playlist configuration options. You may also have provided a file that's not supported by JW Player (like .wmv video). See Supported Media Formats for the list of formats the player does support. https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403682-common-error-messages